# Why was Michael Myers not in Halloween 3?

Tags: halloween-3-season-of-the-witch

Anyone know why Myers was missing from Halloween 3?

Out of all the Halloweens, 3 was completely out of place, not only because it excluded the main evil character, which defines the entire sequel, but also the movie (and acting) was by far the worst I have ever seen. All the other Halloweens are great, except the 3rd. It's like the 3rd is not even part of the series and completely out of place. It might as well had been called something different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The creators John Carpenter & Debra Hill were, to put it bluntly, done with Michael Myers after the second movie and wanted to move on/do something new.  But the Franchise did carry a noteworthy name so they hoped that the previous 2 movies, that had nothing to do with this one, would fill the theater seats.

It's not unheard of that for the sequel the entire cast or even premise/tone get's altered like in:

- Mean Girls 2
- American Psycho 2
- S. Darko
- Dirty Dancing 2: Havana Nights

But for their grand scheme of things, they wanted to make a horror Anthology series. They hoped to make a new Halloween movie each year that stands separate from the other movies (inspired by The Twilight Zone).

Source : Muir, John Kenneth (2012), Horror Films of the 1980s, McFarland, ISBN 9780786455010

Comment: Ok sure, but 4 and 5 picked it back up where 2 left off and rather very nicely too I may add. Then the curse, H20, resurrection,  and now still new ones upcoming. They would have done just fine/better with 3 cut off altogether.

Comment: @Steve237 that's because after the critical and commercial fail of the third movie the studio that owned the franchise went back to Myers but without John Carpenter & Debra Hill. Also the Franchise has been such a fail that they did a soft-reboot. The 2018 version is the new Sequel, and besides the that one and the first one nothing is canon anymore.

Comment: How's 2018 a new sequel. Seems like the story continues with Laurie...So they'll have 2018, 2021 and 2022 (where they're finally going to End it! - Wonder how, as this guy's immortal)

Comment: @Steve237 the 2018 version continues the story from the first one, ignoring Halloween 2, 4 and 5. As if they never happened.

Comment: k got it Thx! Never seen those yet!